# Having problems with MySql

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I installed Ubuntu headless server 14.04 yesterday. The only thing, at that point, that I installed was ssh. I updated the server then installed Plesk with their automated install script.

This is a virtual server running on hyper-v. I have 12 cores, 16gb ram, and a 500gb hd alloted it.

I accessed the website without issue. I do not have a valid ssl certificate yet as I hadn't gotten that far. I then installed the license for Plesk. I did a little snooping around to see how it works and then went to bed. I started this morning on it and the site wouldn't come up. I kept getting connection refused when I tried to access the site. I read around and it said to try [this to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi):

```
cd /var 
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo chmod 755 mysql
cd mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

This allowed me to access the site. When I try to do anything in the site, I get this:

> ERROR: PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database:
>   mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>   (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and
>   accessible. (Abstract.php:69)

I checked the logs in /var/log/mysql/error.log, the mysql.error was zero bytes:

```
151126 10:59:24 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
151126 10:59:24 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
151126 10:59:24 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
151126 10:59:24 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) starting as process 3082 ...
151126 10:59:24 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
151126 10:59:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151126 10:59:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
151126 10:59:24  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

I have not made any changes other than what I stated above. Anyone have any suggestions where to look or what to do?

Additional Info:

```
[24-Nov-2015 20:23:38 America/Chicago] PHP Warning: chgrp(): Operation not permitted; File: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Plesk/Log.php, Line: 66

[2015-11-24 20:23:38] ERR [1] PHP Warning: chgrp(): Operation not permitted; File: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Plesk/Log.php, Line: 66

[2015-11-24 20:24:19] ERR [1] Module configs is not installed.
[2015-11-24 21:18:21] ERR [panel] [Action Log] Failed login attempt with login 'techguyalabama' from IP 50.2.213.12
[2015-11-24 21:18:28] ERR [panel] [Action Log] Failed login attempt with login 'admin' from IP 50.2.213.12
[2015-11-25 09:30:45] ERR [util_exec] proc_close() failed ['/opt/psa/admin/bin/spammng' '--status'] with exit code [1]
[2015-11-25 09:30:45] ERR [1] '/opt/psa/admin/bin/spammng' '--status' failed with code 1.

stdout:


stderr:
ERROR:spammng:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/default/spamassassin'

[2015-11-25 12:49:51] ERR [panel] [Action Log] Failed login attempt with login '<invalid>' from IP 104.238.110.138
[2015-11-26 06:25:03] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:27:18] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 10:27:18] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:51:37] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 10:51:37] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:59:31] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:59:32] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:59:32] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 10:59:32] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:08:57] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/api-common/AbstractCu.php:1640
        AbstractCu::initDb()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/api-common/AbstractCu.php:1666
        AbstractCu::initCLI()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/scripts/setup-health-monitor.php:5
[2015-11-26 11:08:57] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:09:08] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:13:47] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:13:47] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:22:41] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:22:41] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:22:41] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:23:32] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 11:23:32] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:23:52] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 11:23:52] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:23:56] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 11:23:56] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
[2015-11-26 11:24:00] ERR [panel] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.:
0: /opt/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:69
        CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
1: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:150
        Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
2: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:325
        AutoPrepend->initUserSession()
3: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:230
        AutoPrepend->run()
4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/auth.php:759
[2015-11-26 11:24:00] ERR [1] Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible.
```

A little more info:

Searched for the mysqld.sock and mysql.sock:

```
> sudo find . -name mysqld.sock
> sudo find . -name mysql.sock
./var/mysql/mysql.sock
> sudo find . -name my.cnf
./etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Checked out my.cnf and it had this:

```
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

This directory is empty:  /var/run/mysqld

I'm not that familiar with the MySql setup but I figured I'd share this...

Comment: I think you might have to edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Because MySQL miss located your MySQL pid-file and socket path location. For reference, see [this](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this today. I just stopped mysql and started it again:

```
# service mysql stop
mysql stop/waiting
# service mysql start
mysql start/running, process 4042
```

I am unsure about a proper fix for this.

### Edit:

After tailing `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I determined that there were multiple versions of mysql attempting to run. I removed `/etc/init.d/mysql` and did not receive this error on next reboot.

### Edit 2:

**BACKUP `/etc/init.d/mysql` FIRST**

```
# This will maintian all file ownership and permissions
# and back this up in your home directory:
cp -ar /etc/init.d/mysql "$HOME"
```